# Python Script to download images and videos from a user's profile on Instagram

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

The script downloads images and videos from a user's profile page on Instagram. It works fine, but I'd like to know if there are ways to improve it. All ideas and suggestions are welcome.

```
import sys
import os
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
import json
from colorama import init, deinit
from termcolor import colored, cprint
import argparse

print_green = lambda x: cprint(x, 'green')          #print out text in green 
print_magenta   = lambda x : cprint(x, 'magenta')   #print out text in magenta
print_yellow    = lambda x: cprint(x, 'yellow')     #print out text in yellow
print_cyan      = lambda x: cprint(x, 'cyan')       #print out text in cyan

# download images
def image_downloader(edge, images_path):
    display_url = edge['node']['display_url']
    file_name = edge['node']['taken_at_timestamp']
    download_path = images_path + '\\' + str(file_name) + '.jpg'
    if not os.path.exists(download_path):
        print_yellow('Downloading ' + str(file_name) + '.jpg...........')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(display_url, download_path)
        print_green(str(file_name) + '.jpg Downloaded')
        print('\n')
    else:
        print_green(str(file_name) + '.jpg has been downloaded before')
        print('\n')

# download videos   
def video_downloader(shortcode, videos_path):
    r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/' + shortcode + '/?__a=1')
    video_url = r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['video_url']
    file_name = r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']
    download_path = videos_path + '\\' + str(file_name) + '.mp4'
    if not os.path.exists(download_path):
        print_yellow('Downloading ' + str(file_name) + '.mp4...........')
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, download_path)
        print_green(str(file_name) + '.mp4 Downloaded')
        print('\n')
    else:
        print_green(str(file_name) + '.mp4 has been downloaded before')
        print('\n')

# download images and videos from posts containing more than one pictures or videos`
def sidecar_downloader(shortcode, images_path, videos_path):
    r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/' + shortcode + '/?__a=1')
    num = 1
    for edge in r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
        is_video = edge['node']['is_video']
        if is_video == False:
            display_url = edge['node']['display_url']
            file_name = r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']
            download_path = images_path + '\\' + str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.jpg'
            if not os.path.exists(download_path):
                print_yellow('Downloading ' + str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.jpg...........')
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(display_url, download_path)
                print_green(str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.jpg Downloaded')
                print('\n')
            else:
                print_green(str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.jpg has been downloaded before')
                print('\n')
        else:
            video_url = edge['node']['video_url']
            file_name = r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']
            download_path = videos_path + '\\' + str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.mp4'
            if not os.path.exists(download_path):
                print_yellow('Downloading ' + str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.mp4...........')
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, download_path)
                print_green(str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.mp4 Downloaded')
                print('\n')
            else:
                print_green(str(file_name) + '_' + str(num) + '.mp4 has been downloaded before')
                print('\n')
        num += 1

def main(account_json_info, path):
    init()
    r = requests.get(account_json_info)     
    user_id = r.json()['graphql']['user']['id']
    end_cursor = ''
    next_page = True
    is_video = False
    images_path = path + '\\Images'
    videos_path = path + '\\Videos'
    if os.path.exists(path) == False:
        os.makedirs(path)
        if os.path.exists(images_path) == False:
            os.makedirs(images_path)
        if os.path.exists(videos_path) == False:
            os.makedirs(videos_path)
        print_magenta('User Folder Created!\n')
    else:
        print_magenta('User Folder Has Been Created Before!\n')

    while next_page == True:
        r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/', 
                params = {
                    'query_id': '17880160963012870', 
                    'id': user_id,
                    'first': 12, 
                    'after': end_cursor
                }
        )
        graphql = r.json()['data']
        for edge in graphql['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']:
            __typename = edge['node']['__typename']
            if __typename == 'GraphImage':
                image_downloader(edge, images_path)
            elif __typename == 'GraphVideo':
                shortcode = edge['node']['shortcode']
                video_downloader(shortcode, videos_path)
            elif __typename == 'GraphSidecar':
                shortcode = edge['node']['shortcode']
                sidecar_downloader(shortcode, images_path, videos_path)

        end_cursor = graphql['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['end_cursor']
        next_page = graphql['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['has_next_page']
        time.sleep(10)
    deinit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n\n')
    init(autoreset = True)
    print_cyan('Instagram Media Downloader'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns, '-'))
    deinit()
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Download Instagram Images and Videos from a User\'s Profile Page')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--user', dest = 'username', required = True, help = 'Username on Instagram')
    parser.add_argument('-p', '--path', dest = 'path', required = True, help = 'Root path where downloaded Instagram Media is saved')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    account_json_info = 'https://www.instagram.com/' + args.username + '/?__a=1' #insert username into the link
    args.path += '\\' + args.username   #add username to the directory given
    main(account_json_info, args.path)
```

Answer (score 2):

- **Organizing Imports**: I ordered your import statements alphabetically. While this is not a required style point, it's a person preference that you can decide to follow if you want.
- **Unused Imports**: You had a few unused imports (`json`, `sys`, `termcolor`)
- **String Formatting**: You concatenate multiple strings with variables everywhere in your code. You can format your string with `f"..."`, so you can directly implement variables in your strings, like so: `download_path = f"{videos_path}\\{file_name}.mp4"`.
- **Variable Assignment/Parameter Spacing**: There should only be one space before the `=` and after the `=` when assigning variables. For default parameters, there should be no spaces. I'm not sure if this is a practice that's taught, but it's how I learned my python styling.
- **DRY**: Don't Repeat Yourself! Your `print_...` lambda's do the exact same thing, with only one string being different. These four lambdas can be simplified to a simple method, with passing the text and color to print. *I'm pretty sure `termcolor` has a built-in method `colored` that does the exact thing, but I'd have to double check*.
- **Truth/False Comparisons**: As an example, `if is_video == False` should be changed to `if not is_video`. It does the exact same thing, without the verbose `== False`, and utilizing `not`. You use both ways in your code, but you should really avoid `== False`/`== True`.
- **Constant Variable Names**: Variables that are constants should be UPPERCASE.
- **Docstrings**: You had the right idea with regular comments describing what the method does. You should move these comments into a docstring inside the method, so any documentation can tell what your method is supposed to do.

***Final Code***

```
import argparse
import os
import requests
import time
import urllib.request
from colorama import init, deinit
from termcolor import cprint

def print_in_color(text, color):
    """ Prints `text` in passed `color` """
    cprint(text, color)

def image_downloader(edge, images_path):
    """ Downloads images """
    display_url = edge['node']['display_url']
    file_name = edge['node']['taken_at_timestamp']
    download_path = f"{images_path}\\{file_name}.jpg"
    if not os.path.exists(download_path):
        print_in_color(f"Downloading {str(file_name)}.jpg...........", "yellow")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(display_url, download_path)
        print_in_color(f"{file_name}.jpg downloaded.\n", "green")
    else:
        print_in_color(f"{file_name}.jpg has been downloaded already.\n", "green")

def video_downloader(shortcode, videos_path):
    """ Downloads videos """
    videos = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/p/{shortcode}/?__a=1")
    video_url = videos.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['video_url']
    file_name = videos.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']
    download_path = f"{videos_path}\\{file_name}.mp4"
    if not os.path.exists(download_path):
        print_in_color(f"Downloading {file_name}.mp4...........", "yellow")
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, download_path)
        print_in_color(f"{file_name}.mp4 downloaded.\n", "green")
    else:
        print_in_color(f"{file_name}.mp4 has been downloaded already.\n", "green")

def sidecar_downloader(shortcode, images_path, videos_path):
    """ Downloads images and videos from posts containing more than one pictures or videos """
    r = requests.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/p/{shortcode}/?__a=1")
    num = 1
    for edge in r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['edge_sidecar_to_children']['edges']:
        is_video = edge['node']['is_video']
        if not is_video:
            display_url = edge['node']['display_url']
            file_name = r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']
            download_path = f"{images_path}\\{file_name}_{num}.jpg"
            if not os.path.exists(download_path):
                print_in_color(f"Downloading {file_name}_{num}.jpg...........", "yellow")
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(display_url, download_path)
                print_in_color(f"{file_name}_{num}.jpg downloaded.\n", "green")
            else:
                print_in_color(f"{file_name}_{num}.jpg has been downloaded already.\n", "green")
        else:
            video_url = edge['node']['video_url']
            file_name = r.json()['graphql']['shortcode_media']['taken_at_timestamp']
            download_path = f"{videos_path}\\{file_name}_{num}.mp4"
            if not os.path.exists(download_path):
                print_in_color(f"Downloading {file_name}_{num}.mp4...........", "yellow")
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(video_url, download_path)
                print_in_color(f"{file_name}_{num}.mp4 downloaded.\n", "green")
            else:
                print_in_color(f"{file_name}_{num}.mp4 has been downloaded already.\n", "green")
        num += 1

def main(account_json_info, path):
    """ Runs methods that download photos/videos from the user """
    init()
    r = requests.get(account_json_info)
    user_id = r.json()['graphql']['user']['id']
    end_cursor = ''
    next_page = True
    images_path = f"{path}\\Images"
    videos_path = f"{path}\\Videos"
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
        if not os.path.exists(images_path):
            os.makedirs(images_path)
        if not os.path.exists(videos_path):
            os.makedirs(videos_path)
        print_in_color("User Folder Created!\n", "magenta")
    else:
        print_in_color("User Folder Has Been Created Already!\n", "magenta")

    while next_page:
        r = requests.get('https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/',
                params={
                    'query_id': '17880160963012870',
                    'id': user_id,
                    'first': 12,
                    'after': end_cursor
                }
            )
        graphql = r.json()['data']
        for edge in graphql['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']:
            __typename = edge['node']['__typename']
            if __typename == 'GraphImage':
                image_downloader(edge, images_path)
            elif __typename == 'GraphVideo':
                shortcode = edge['node']['shortcode']
                video_downloader(shortcode, videos_path)
            elif __typename == 'GraphSidecar':
                shortcode = edge['node']['shortcode']
                sidecar_downloader(shortcode, images_path, videos_path)

        end_cursor = graphql['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['end_cursor']
        next_page = graphql['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info']['has_next_page']
        time.sleep(10)
    deinit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n\n')
    init(autoreset=True)
    print_in_color('Instagram Media Downloader'.center(os.get_terminal_size().columns, '-'), "cyan")
    deinit()

    PARSER = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Download Instagram Images and Videos from a User\'s Profile Page')
    PARSER.add_argument('-u', '--user', dest='username', required=True, help='Username on Instagram')
    PARSER.add_argument('-p', '--path', dest='path', required=True, help='Root path where downloaded Instagram Media is saved')
    ARGS = PARSER.parse_args()

    #Insert username into link
    ACCOUNT_JSON_INFO = f"https://www.instagram.com/{ARGS.username}/?__a=1"
    ARGS.path += f"\\{ARGS.username}"
    main(ACCOUNT_JSON_INFO, ARGS.path)
```

Comment: Import standard in python is to import standard library packages/modules as one block first, then external packages/modules as another block, then personal packages/modules - each block separated by an empty line.